# The Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.BizTalk.WcfBtsSqlReceiver assembly (version 3.5.0.0) compatibility issue with 64-bit Office 365

Tags: sql, office365, biztalk, compatibility

After upgraded Office 365 64 bit from Office 2016 32 bit, I keep getting the following error when I use BizTalk server:
The Messaging Engine failed to creae the receive adapter "WCF-SQL". InboundAssemblyPath: "NULL" InboundTypeName: "Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.BizTalk.WcfBtsSqlReceiver, Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.BizTalk, Version=3.5.0.0
[image]

Comment: Check of the host instance you are using is a 32 bit or 64 bit one.  But why upgrading Office 365 should impact it at all is strange.   Check that system environment variable still includes the biztalk folders, e.g. for BizTalk 2013

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\Bins32;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\Bins64`

Comment: That is the Path environment setting

Comment: I was able to fix it by installing Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack (x64). Thanks!

Comment: You should post that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by installing Microsoft BizTalk Adapter Pack (x64).